# Is there a way to reverse the dropping method in pandas?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm aware that you can use 
`df1 = df1[df1['Computer Name'] != 'someNameToBeDropped']`
to drop a given string as a row

what if i wanted to do it the other way around. Let's say dropping everything except what i have in a list of strings.

is there a simple hack I haven't noticed?

Comment: `df1 = df1[df1['Computer Name'] == 'someNameNOTToBeDropped']` ?

Comment: @harvpan has the correct solution but, `~` is an interesting operator.  `df1[~(df1['Computer Name'] != 'someNameToBeDropped')]`

Comment: harv has the correct solution given there are only two names in the column's possible values. For `n` values, `~` is the way to go ;p

Comment: NB: all good above but I prefer to use `loc` as it is a vectorized built in method

`df1 = df1.loc[~(df1['Computer Name'] != 'someNameToBeDropped'), :]`

Comment: But does it drop everything else except 'someNameNOTToBeDropped' ?

Comment: Dropping everything except something = Looking for something. `df1[df1['Computer Name'] == 'someNameNOTToBeDropped']` with `==` returns rows with `ComputerName` = `someNameNOTToBeDropped`. Use `df.loc[df['col'].isin(mylist)]` for multiple strings.

Comment: Alright, thank you everyone for the answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to get rows such that value of col is in that given list

```
df = df[df[column].isin(list_of_strings)]
```

Additional to exclude what's in the list

```
df = df[~df[column].isin(list_of_values)]
```