# Extract unique value with multiple columns from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe where I want to extract values from two columns but the criteria set is unique values from one of the columns. In the image below, I want to extract unique values of 'education' along with its corresponding values from 'education-num'. I can easily extract the unique values with `df['education'].unique()` and I am stuck with not being able to extract the 'education-num'.

[image of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uySWA.jpg).

(Originally the task was to compute the population of people with education of Bachelors, Masters and Doctorate and I assume this would be easier when comparing the 'education-num' rather than logical operators on string. But if there's any way we could do it directly from the 'education' that would also be helpful.

Edit: Turns out the `Dataframe.isin` helps to select rows by the list of string as given in the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57580177/is-there-a-way-to-reverse-the-dropping-method-in-pandas/57580432).)

P.S. stack-overflow didn't allow me to post the image directly and posted a link to it instead...

Comment: the code you provided resulted same as `df[['education','education-num']]` with the only difference of removing the column name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select columns by subset and call [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df1 = df[['education', 'education-num']].drop_duplicates()
```

If need count population use:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['education', 'education-num']).size().reset_index(name='count')
```